# How can i pass ViewData to Action method from class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to replace

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
ViewData["SomeData"] = ...
return View();
}
```

with

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
 _someDataCretor.Create(...);
return View();
}
```

What should happen in SomeDataCretor.Create() for this to work? For View to get ViewData.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `ViewData` is defined as `public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }`. Therefore you can pass it as a parameter to your method:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    _someDataCretor.Create(ViewData);
    return View();
}
```

And in the `Create(ViewDataDictionary viewdata)` method:

```cs
viewdata["SomeData"] = ...;
```

***But I suppose a more reasonable approach is to return an object from the `Create()` method that will be passed to the `Index` view as a view model.***

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `_someDataCreator` contains the data you want in the view, you would just pass it as the model:

```
return View(_someDataCreator);
```

or if it returns an object you can return that result:

```
var result = _someDateCreator.Create(...);
return View(result);
```

and in your view reference that type:

```
@model My.Namespace.MyObject
```

Answer (score 2):

`ViewData` is used to pass data from controllers to views and within views, including partial views and layouts.You can try to use `TempData`,here is a demo:

```
public class MyDepedency
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;

        public MyDepedency(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        }

        public void Create()
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(httpContext);

            // use tempData as usual
            tempData["SomeData"] = "Bar";
        }
     
    }
```

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<MyDepedency, MyDepedency>();
        }
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public MyDepedency _myDepedency;
       
        public HomeController(MyDepedency myDepedency)
        {
            _myDepedency = myDepedency;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _myDepedency.Create();
            return View();
            
        }
```

View:

```
<h1>@TempData.Peek("SomeData")</h1>
```

result:
[image]